# AWK match lines with at least 2 digits and at least 2 letters in any order

Tags: awk

My job is to `match lines with at least 2 digits and at least 2 letters in any order` ( some letters are separated by digits ) using AWK.

Here is my sample.txt:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456

1a
b23
3c4d
e5f67
gj34qz
```

My AWK version is GNU Awk 4.0.1 ( Ubuntu Linux ).

I've been trying to do it this way:

`awk '/[0-9]{2,}/ && /[a-z]{2,}/' sample.txt`

or

`awk '/[[:digit:]]{2,}/ && /[[:lower:]]{2,}/' sample.txt`

but it is not working right way ( it catches only continuous strings ) for example it skips:

`3c4d`

and

`e5f67`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow characters between with `.*`:

```
awk '/[0-9].*[0-9]/ && /[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]/'
```

Precisely two letters:

```
awk '/[0-9].*[0-9]/ && /^[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*$/'
```

Comment: +1 my answer (almost) exactly: `awk '/[[:digit:]].*[[:digit:]]/ && /[[:alpha:]].*[[:alpha:]]/'`

Comment: It's working thanks I was so close :). Maybe You know a little different scenario if there will be small change that we want to catch at least 2 digits and ONLY 2 letters (again order no matter)?

Comment: @mike you have to anchor the regex to make sure it matches the whole string, and use `[^a-zA-Z]` instead of `.`. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub` function's return value to calculate how many digits and alphabets were present in the line.

`gsub` function returns the number of substitution made. So you can do:

```
awk '{l=$0;if(gsub(/[[:digit:]]/,x)>=2 && gsub(/[[:lower:]]/,x)>=2) print l}' file
```

We store the line in a variable `l` since after `gsub` runs the original line is modified. We check the return value of `gsub` to be `>=2`. If both conditions are true, we print the line.

With your sample data, it outputs:

```
$ awk '{l=$0;if(gsub(/[[:digit:]]/,x)>=2 && gsub(/[[:lower:]]/,x)>=2) print l}' file
3c4d
e5f67
gj34qz
```

Comment: **Note:** Use this solution if your range changes for example 6 or more characters of each type. Then you can simply modify the `if` condition to be `>=6` but for current condition [Kevin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22209725/970195) should work well.